# Add a tick to button when selected in Angular 2 app

Tags: html, css, angular

I am new to `Angular 2` and I'm after do a custom button display when selected.  For questions I have 2 buttons for the answer which only one is allowed to be selected (I have all this working) but what I'd like to do is add a tick in from of the selected buttons value.

I know it will need to be done in CSS, which is fine, but I don't know how to do it.

I tried the below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
.md-fab.md-primary.md-grey-ajb-red-theme.md-button, .md-raised.md-primary.md-grey-ajb-red-theme.md-button
{
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content:"\e089";
}
```

Below is an example of what I want.  When the button not selected or un-selected the button should just say 'Yes' and obviously have a different colour:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.md-fab.md-primary.md-grey-ajb-red-theme.md-button, .md-raised.md-primary.md-grey-ajb-red-theme.md-button
{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.md-fab.md-primary.md-grey-ajb-red-theme.md-button:before, .md-raised.md-primary.md-grey-ajb-red-theme.md-button:before
{
    content:"\e089";
    display: block;
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px; // adjust as per your need
    left: 110px; // adjust as per your need
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it does nothing at all, no image or anything

Comment: Please inspect and check if the button is generating psuedo elements or not.

Answer (score 0):

take a boolean variable to set the class on off and render the text on button click. Call a method on click which will change the button text.